# ClassCastException Java RMI Notification Framework

Tags: java, server, client, rmi

I am trying to make my application in two packages in order to simulate it later on two different machines, but when I do that I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to client.RemoteServer
at client.NotificationSink.<init>(NotificationSink.java:34)
at client.NotificationSink.main(NotificationSink.java:20)
```

I guess that I have to move the class RemoteImplementation in the client too, to avoid this exception. But I am sure whether my whole structure is correct.

My questions:
**How to fix this Exception?
Is my overall structure correct (I am building Notification framework)?**

[image]

Comment: Does RemoteServer an interface?

Comment: Yes, It is an interface as well as RemoteClient.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html

Comment: If `RemoteServer` is an Interface, then it has to be in a shared namespace ... If you have client.RemoteServer and server.RemoteServer you could as well have named them client.Sue and server.Sally ... yu wouldn't have expected to be able to cast Sue to Sally right?

Answer (score 0):

I think  this generally means that you have two intercaes `RemoteServer`  present in your system, both of which have loaded the server , and that you're trying to pass an instance created using one proxy copy of the class to code expecting the other.
Try to delete one of client.RemoteServer.

Comment: In RemoteServer I have the method register(RemoteClient c) and in RemoteClient I have inform(Notification n). So I should transfer both methods in one inteface?(Both interfaces extend Remote).

Comment: @Nikola Try it to transfer all methods in one interface

Comment: @Nikola No. There is no reason to combine the interfaces. One is for the server, the other is for the client. But you can't have two copies of the same interface in different packages and expect it to work. Normally there is a third package and a third JAR file for stuff that is common between the server and the client.